# How to call a method when clicking button

Tags: acumatica

Very unfamiliar with Acumatica, I am trying to make a button clickable that I configured on the Employee Time Card screen.  I want it to call a method when clicked but I have been unsuccessful.

Here is my the screen.  The button is labeled PUNCH CARD.

[image]

Made some changes:

When I click on the PUNCH CARD button I do see a POST back to the server:  https://dev.domain.tld/db/(W(20))/pages/ep/ep305000.aspx?PopupPanel=Inline&HideScript=On&TimeCardCD=TC00000001
I think I should be seeing some exception response on the screen but I see nothing.

Here is the aspx code.  I don't know what to put in the DependOnGrid attribute.  I just copied what was on Yuri Zaletskyy's blog.  Is this always set to this or is there something specific to the site / page I am working with?  If so how do I determine what to put here?

```
<px:PXToolBarButton Text="Punch Card" Visible="True" DependOnGrid="grdJiraProjects">
    <AutoCallBack Target="" Enabled="True" Command="punchCard">
      <Behavior CommitChanges="True" /></AutoCallBack>
    <PopupCommand>
      <Behavior CommitChanges="True" />
</PopupCommand></px:PXToolBarButton>
```

C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using PX.Common;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.CT;
using PX.Objects.PM;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using PX.SM;
using PX.TM;
using PX.Web.UI;
using Branch = PX.Objects.GL.Branch;
using System.Text;
using PX.Objects.GL.FinPeriods.TableDefinition;
using PX.Objects.GL.FinPeriods;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.EP;

namespace TimeTracking
{
  public class TimeCardMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.EP.TimeCardMaint>
  {   
    public PXSelect<PMTimeActivity> PMTimeActivity;
    public PXAction<EPTimeCard> PunchCard;

    #region Event Handlers
    protected void EPTimecardDetail_UsrPIXIClockIn_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
    {
      if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
        InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
      var row = (PMTimeActivity)e.Row;
      var rows = row.GetExtension<PMTimeActivityExt>();
      updateTotalHours(cache, rows, row);
    }

    protected void EPTimecardDetail_UsrPIXIClockOut_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
    {      
      if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
        InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
      var row = (PMTimeActivity)e.Row;
      var rows = row.GetExtension<PMTimeActivityExt>();
      updateTotalHours(cache, rows, row);
    }   
    #endregion

    public void punchCard()
    {
      throw new PXException("You Clicked Punch Time Card on Action Bar");     
    }

    public void updateTotalHours(PXCache cache, PMTimeActivityExt rows, PMTimeActivity row)
    {
       if (rows.UsrPIXIClockIn != null && rows.UsrPIXIClockOut != null)
        {
        DateTime dtClockIn = DateTime.Parse(rows.UsrPIXIClockIn.ToString());
        DateTime dtClockOut = DateTime.Parse(rows.UsrPIXIClockOut.ToString());
        double total = (dtClockOut - dtClockIn).TotalHours;
        rows.UsrPIXITotalHours = (decimal) total;
        }

    }        
  }
}
```

Comment: In Acumatica instance folder on the website server, after publishing customization there will be a CstPublished folder that contains the customized screen ASPX file. EP305000.aspx in your case. Adding that as well as the graph code files you have to your stack overflow questions can help better understand what is missing from your current solution. As is, I can only tell that you successfully added the button to the grid (which is a good start).

Comment: DependOnGrid property should point to grid at your page. I'm suspicious you don't have at your page grid with name grdJiraProjects. DependOnGrid notifies button, from where it can take current property

Answer (score 0):

One common catch that results in the button action event handler not being called is   using the wrong DAC for the action generic type parameter.

Make sure the action generic type matches the graph primary DAC. In your case this would be `EPTimeCard`:

```
public PXAction<EPTimeCard> PunchCard;
```

Do you have a Graph Extension?
That's where you should put the action event handler for the button.

In your case `TimeCardMaint` is the graph of the employee time card screen:

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Web.UI;
using System.Collections;

namespace PX.Objects.EP
{
    public class TimeCardMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<TimeCardMaint>
    {
        public PXAction<EPTimeCard> PunchCard;

        [PXButton]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Punch Card")]
        public virtual IEnumerable punchCard(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            // This is where you handle button click event
            return adapter.Get();
        }
    }
}
```

There is something special about the button you added. It is located in a grid toolbar. It's often the case that you want grid toolbar actions to operate on the currently selected line. For that to work you need to declare the action in ASP file and set it's `DependOnGrid` property:

This is explained in more details here:
http://blog.zaletskyy.com/dependongrid-in-acumatica-or-how-to-get-currently-selected-record-in-grid

This link could help you too:
http://blog.zaletskyy.com/add-button-to-grid-in-acumatica

Once everything is setup you could then access the currently selected record in the grid from your action event handler like this:

```
[PXButton]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Punch Card")]
public virtual IEnumerable punchCard(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    EPTimeCardDetail row = Base.Activities.Current as EPTimeCardDetail;

    if (row != null)
    {
        // Presumably do some Punch Card action on selected row from Details tab Activities grid
    }

    return adapter.Get();
}
```